# How to improve Performance of website according to google new Algorithms

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Recently google has changed and updated its algorithms for SEO, that is why GTmertix changed its reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please implement advanced JS Bundling
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html